# Performing calculations on form inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have designed a food menu webpage with checkboxes and radio boxes. I use PHP to retrieve results from a MySQL database table. The code below shows an example of how things are set up currently:

PHP includes to connect to database:

```
  <?php include('includes/fruits.php');?>
  <?php include('includes/cheese.php');?>
  <?php include('includes/desert.php');?>
```

An example of one of the PHP includes:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username    enter code here
$password="admin2"; // Mysql password    enter code here
$db_name="food"; // Database name    enter code here
$tbl_name="fruits"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");     
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result_fruits=mysql_query($sql);
```

The input boxes on main page that return the table data (each category is in it's own MySQL table):

```
<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result_fruits)){ ?>
<input type="radio" name="fruits[]" id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['label']; ?>" class="green-border-fruits"  />

<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result_cheese)){ ?>
<input type="radio" name="cheese[]" id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['label']; ?>" class="green-border-cheese"  />

<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result_desert)){ ?>
<input type="radio" name="desert[]" id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['label']; ?>" class="green-border-desert"  />
```

So, for example, the above code would return:

```
apple  $2<br> 
orange $1<br>
grapes $2

<td>
swiss $3<br></td>
blue cheese $1.50<br>
feta $2.20

cake $5<br>
pie $4<br>
cookies $3.50
```

I need the total of all CHECKED items to be displayed in a textbox.

EX: this would be the amount displayed if (apple, orange, blue cheese, and pie were checked)

> TOTAL - **$8.50**

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"So, for example, the above code would return"* - Would, should, will, or "does"?

Comment: The code WILL return the each items value. So once I change the VALUE attribute to "value="<? echo $rows[price]; ?>" , it will result as mentioned above. I didn't set it yet though. GOOD POINT BTW

Comment: I will check this out tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: `array_sum()` could come in handy for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery to check what radio buttons are selected and then sum all values and put the result with .html in the textfield.

check radio buttons:

```
var value = $('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()
```

And you can loop through all radio buttons with:

```
$('.className').each(function() {
 // do stuff here
}
```

Combined example:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.radioButtonClass').each(function() {
     if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     sum = sum + $(this).val();
}
$("#idTextfield").html("Total: " + sum + "$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.total').click(function() {

v = 0;
$('.sum').each(function() {

if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
v+= parseFloat($(this).val());
}

});

alert(v);

});

});
</script>

<input class="sum" type="radio" name="fruits[]" id="" value="10.00" class="green-border-fruits"  /> 10.00 ....

<input type="button" class="total" value="sum">
```